# Deployment dedicated project does not work with VS 2012

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, solution

I have a complex application that is split into two projects, and a deployment project.

- MySolution.sln

  - Core.csproj
  - Client.csproj
  - Deployment.csproj

The deployment project is setup to include all sharepoint artefacts from the two other project. There's absolutely no other code in this project.

I added in the package designer, all artifacts that should be packaged.

I also added the reference to the two projects.

With VS 2010, this is working perfectly. I can set up the project deployment as the startup project. When I press F5, everything compiles and deploy.

With VS 2012, however, the solution compiles, but the project do not deploy.

I'm getting some compilation errors, stating that some namespace is missing. The error belongs to the deployment project, while the error show code from the first project.

What should I do to keep this structure with VS 2012?

**[Edit]** A reproduction project has been shared on my skydrive: http://sdrv.ms/1aCbAYS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend gave me the answer.

In the project's references, I have to set `Copy local` to `false`.

If it's `true`, the Visual Studio tools mess up between the DLL that come from the artifact and the DLL that is found locally.

Not only this solved the issue, but it also set up properly the safe controls entry.